# different ldapsearches , no output

Tags: openldap

when I use

```
ldapsearch -LLLZZ -H ldap://centos7s.domen.lan -x
```

I get everything out:

```
dn: dc=domen,dc=lan
objectClass: domain
dc: domen
o: domen.lan organization
description: The Domen Company

dn: ou=users,dc=domen,dc=lan
ou: users
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: ou=groups,dc=domen,dc=lan
ou: groups
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: uid=ldapuser1,ou=users,dc=domen,dc=lan
uid: ldapuser1
cn: ldapuser1
sn: ldapuser1
mail: ldapuser1@domen.lan
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson....
```

but with

```
ldapsearch  -ZZWD cn=manager,dc=domen,dc=lan -b cn=config -h centos7s.domen.lan
```

I get nothing :

```
Enter LDAP Password:
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <cn=config> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 3
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

What did I do wrong? What is the difference with this searches ?

In original I have:

```
ldapsearch -LLLY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(olcAccess=*)' olcAccess olcSuffix
```

-

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth" manage by * none

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by 

dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
     ,cn=auth" read    by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=domen,dc=lan" read    by * none
```

Now, after change:

```
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth" manage by * none

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth" read    by dn.base="cn=manager,dc=domen,dc=lan" read    by * none

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
olcSuffix: dc=domen,dc=lan
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange   by dn="cn=manager,dc=do
 men,dc=lan" write   by anonymous auth   by self write   by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base=""   by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=manager,dc=domen,dc=lan" write   by * read
```

Still the same result as above, second `ldapsearch`  returns nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two searches have different search bases. Check your ACLs for more information.

All I know at a for sure is that:

1. `anonymous` has some access to the `dc=domen,dc=lan` subtree.
2. `cn=manager,dc=domen,dc=lan` has no access to the `cn=config` subtree.

Comment: I have updated the question to show ACL-s.